# How does Mathematica find the process parameter?

Tags: algorithm, internals

I want to know what kind of algorithm is used by Mathematica's [`Estimated Process`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedProcess.html).

For example, we can estimate the parameter as follows:

```
data = RandomFunction[PoissonProcess[.4], {0, 10^2}];
eproc = EstimatedProcess[data, PoissonProcess[λ]]
```

How does Mathematica find `λ`?

Comment: does the material in [ProcessEstimator >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProcessEstimator.html) answer your question?

Comment: @kglr Definitely! thank you!